# UIView Popup like UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, xcode4, uialertview

I Want a UIView which can popup like UIAlertView and also can move.

Any help please??

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Animate the view's transform using UIView animation ([using blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW108) or [older api](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW62))

from some really small size (like `view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1)`) to something a little bigger then you want it to be (like `view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1))`, then back to the desired size `(view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1))`, or add more steps for bigger bounce.

And for moving it around, implement the [touch methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006783-CH4-SW13) and change the view's frame as the finger moves.

Edit: here is the sample code for custom UIAlertView-like UIView.

MyAlertView.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyAlertView : UIView {
    CGPoint lastTouchLocation;
    CGRect originalFrame;
    BOOL isShown;
}

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isShown;

- (void)show;
- (void)hide;

@end
```

MyAlertView.m:

```
#import "MyAlertView.h"

@implementation MyAlertView

@synthesize isShown;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        originalFrame = frame;

        self.alpha = 0;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, 20)];
        label.text = @"Hellooooo!";
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        UIButton *closeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, frame.size.height - 45, frame.size.width - 20, 35);
        [closeButton setTitle:@"Close" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hide) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self addSubview:closeButton];
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark Custom alert methods

- (void)show
{
    NSLog(@"show");
    isShown = YES;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    self.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"showAlert" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1);
    self.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)hide
{
    NSLog(@"hide");
    isShown = NO;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"hideAlert" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);
    self.alpha = 0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)toggle
{
    if (isShown) {
        [self hide];
    } else {
        [self show];
    }
}

#pragma mark Animation delegate

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"showAlert"]) {
        if (finished) {
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
            [UIView commitAnimations];
        }
    } else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"hideAlert"]) {
        if (finished) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
            self.frame = originalFrame;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark Touch methods

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint newTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGRect currentFrame = self.frame;

    CGFloat deltaX = lastTouchLocation.x - newTouchLocation.x;
    CGFloat deltaY = lastTouchLocation.y - newTouchLocation.y;

    self.frame = CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x - deltaX, currentFrame.origin.y - deltaY, currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.size.height);
    lastTouchLocation = [touch locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

}

@end
```

Then where you want to show that alert, you need:

```
#import "MyAlertView.h"
```

and:

```
MyAlertView *alert = [[MyAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 100)];
[viewFromWhichYouWillShowTheAlert addSubview:alert];
[alert release];
```

then you show it using `[alert show];`, hide using `[alert hide];`, or toggle using `[alert toggle];`

You can also move it around when you tap and drag (anywhere except on the close button). I hope this is enough to get you started. If you need explanation for any part of code just ask.

Oh, and notice I set the color of this view to white so if you show it on top of other white view, you won't really see it, so just change the background color of any view :)

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire that simply following the following steps

1. Create UIview (ViewA)of size 320*480 , so that it will cover whole screen of iPhone with  background set to clearColor.This will serve as super view for our purpose;
2. Create another UIView (ViewB) of size 320*480 with background color set to black and opacity to 40%.
   3.Now you can add any view on ViewB.
3. Now add ViewB to ViewA.

Finally you can Present this view where ever required. The effect will be, ViewA will cover the Background viewController, ViewB will server as suppressing effect for background view controller and views on B are the UIElement you will see.

For Animation effect you can use some basic animation code on the UIElement on ViewB.