# UIView as AlertView

Tags: ios, xcode

I am woking on a project where i have to show a custom alert view similar to [image: uiview-as-alertview]

I found, that customising UIAlertView is a wrong approach! So the way to achieve it is using UIView, that would Pop-in and Pop-out like UIAlertView using animation.

I have also seen some SOs [question]: [How can I customize an iOS alert view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600779/how-can-i-customize-an-ios-alert-view) and [question]: [UIView Popup like UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965795/uiview-popup-like-uialertview) 
Still i am facing problem, like AlertView not appearing. Can anyone just share some good tutorial on the same.

//Thanks

Comment: Customize alert view and implement its drawRect method.

Answer (score 0):

The system `UIAlertView` creates its own `UIWindow` so it can float above your normal `UIWindow`.  You might want to try that approach.  If you do, you might find some useful hints in [this answer about using extra `UIWindow`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8239705/77567).

Comment: I subclassed UIView class to draw this menu. Then instantiated it to be displayed over parent viewcontroller.  To handle touch events in the parent VC i used Protocol-delegate approach!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Modal View Controller**

A modal view controller is simply a UIViewController class that is presented modally.

To present a view controller in a modal fashion, you can use the method:

```
- (void)presentModalViewController:(UIViewController *)modalViewController animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Change the Frame as a 50% of view and you can apply different Animations to it for representation.

Here are the available modal transition styles

```
yourModelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
yourModelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
yourModelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
yourModelViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
```

**Example Code:**

```
UIViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
controller.frame = yourFrame;
UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [self window] cache: YES];
[self.view presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```