# How to add more than eight buttons in a UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I want to add more than 8 buttons in `UIAlertView` but when I am adding buttons, they are covering each other and not scrolling. The title is also hiding.

How can I resolve this and add some scrolling in the alertview ??

Comment: Nopes... You can't. You had to created the custom view with works in the same way as UIAlertView. Since increasing the no. of buttons, will not allow the alert to scroll.

Comment: go with customview instead of alertview

Comment: Apple docs advice if you are using more than two buttons you should really use `UIActionSheet` this is not a requirement just a recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

[Seems like this kind of question comes up at least once a day on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uialertview), but if you want to mess around with the various components *within* a UIAlertView, the short answer is: **DON'T**.

[If you look at Apple's documentation for UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html), within the first screenful of text it states:

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is and does not
>   support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and
>   must not be modified.

This means that there's a decent chance that any mucking around within UIAlertView hierarchy could catastrophically break your app in future iOS release.

So if you want to add scroll bars or bells & whistles, you really should create your own *custom* UIView (which looks like a UIAlertView, but is wholly of your own creation)

Comment: I always find that everyone finds a lot of confusion around `UIAlertView` subclassing. Whilst I totally agree that if your going to be messing with `UIAlertView`s it would be better to just create your own version using `UIView` or something, but the Apple docs do specify that subclassing is `@interface myAlertView : UIAlertView` and not using `addSubview` it is not recommended but apple do still allow the use of `addSubview` because it isn't subclassing. +1 for links to apple docs

Answer (score 1):

If you have more buttons then **`UIActionSheet`** is the best option than using `UIAlertView`. If you dont want to use `UIActionSheet` there is always a custom View to your rescue!

Comment: this or make an own view and add it as subview

Answer (score 0):

You should really rethink your UI if you need more that 8 button in a `UIAlertView`. 8 button is the maximum the standard alert view can handle.

Either build your own alert view or use a normal view controller with a table view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's necessary but as an alternative, you can present another ViewController/ModalVC that will have all the attributes that you may require....

Comment: Are you talking about a custom alert view?

Comment: It's an idea but I wouldn't say it is the best idea. You may want to update your answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just move ahead with CustomView, Otherwise not possible with UIAlertView to meet up with your requirement :

**Reference links :**

1. http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html
2. http://iosdevtricks.blogspot.in/2013/04/creating-custom-alert-view-for-iphone.html
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6965828/434898

Answer (score -3):

If you want to add many buttons you can use a custom implementation for the alertView. 
A nice example is [FUIAlertView](https://github.com/Grouper/FlatUIKit)

Or you could use [WEpopover](https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover) and add to it a table view.

Comment: The question was how to add more that 8 button to a `UIAlertView` not how to use the `UIAlertView`.