# Disable all interaction UIViewcontroler when push new UIVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I use this code at here [UIView Popup like UIAlertView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965795/uiview-popup-like-uialertview) to create UIVIew same UIalertView. 
I push new UIViewAlert from UIViewController, but i want UIViewAlert appear, UIViewController not tap or select, and then UIViewAlert disappear, UIVIewController tap normal. In my ViewController has 1 tablview, 1 tabbar include 4 UIButton.

I called new UIViewAlert as:

```
    DetailView *detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
    [detailAlert show];
    [detailAlert release];
```

Anybody show me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by adding a `BLOCK SCREEN` before your alertview is launched see the code below

```
self.blockView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
self.blockView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.blockView.alpha = .5;
self.blockView.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
[self.view addSubview:self.blockView];

DetailView *detailAlert = [[DetailView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:detailAlert];
[detailAlert show];
[detailAlert release];
```

Then when you remove your alertview do the following

```
[self.blockView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: thanks, it tried your code but it's a view, cannot disable interaction of viewcontroller

Comment: Try to add `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.blockView];` after adding it to self.view..

Answer (score 0):

You can Display your DetailView with popup.

use this for demo.
https://github.com/martinjuhasz/MJPopupViewController

Comment: Thanks but it will dismiss if you tap background. If i want to click on button, it'll dismiss ???

Comment: please comment this line in  UIViewController+MJPopupViewController.m file                      //[dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissPopupViewControllerWithanimation:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Can it use for UIVIew not UIVIewController ?

Comment: You can use UIViewController instead of UIView

Answer (score 0):

You could create a clear-colored view controller and presented it modally, see example below for Swift 2:

```
private func TransparentViewController() -> UIViewController {
  let transparentViewController = UIViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
  transparentViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
  transparentViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
  transparentViewController.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
  return transparentViewController
}
```

And now you can present it from within your view controller, before presenting the HUD:

```
let transparentViewController = TransparentViewController()
self.presentViewController(transparentViewController, animated:false, completion: nil)
```